# URLFOR misbehaving with Image attachment?

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

Trying to do something which is very simple but am getting strange results.
I have an image stored as an attachment which I want to display in a VF Page.

If I do this it works fine

```
 <apex:image  url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,'00PR0000008Q3YmMAK')}"/>
```

However that was for testing purposes that I hardcoded the id. If I try reference the Id in the object then it fails. Even though the value contained in the object is exactly the same as above.

```
 <apex:image  url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,model.PreviewImageAttachId)}"/>
```

**When I load the page I get an error in URLFOR param!!!**

I thought my problem was because model.PreviewImageAttachId was a String and not an Id so I created a wrapper to return it as an Id - same error.
I then decided Salesforce must have some strange requirement that you can only pass in the REAL object so I did that and passed in model.Attach.Id and it still fails!!

Please can someone explain this to me and more importantly suggest a solution??!?

Once again if I output to the page

```
{!model.PreviewImageAttachId} i get 00PR0000008Q3YmMAK
```

So I just cant explain this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My bad...

Was using apex:repeat and turns out SOME of the id values were null.
Hence the error